# IOS: font custom inside my app

Tags: ios, fonts

I want to insert a font inside my app, it's called "RemachineScript.ttf" and I done these steps:

- I add it in my project and checked it in target membership
- I add it in plist file in section Fonts provided by application with name RemachineScript.ttf
- I install font in my mac

and finally I try to use it in this way

```
[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"RemachineScript" size:30]];
```

but it don't work, I try also

```
[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Remachine Script" size:30]];
```

but nothing.

My question is: are all fonts compatible with xcode projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add font name to plist file and add import file to class.
check step by step in this link
http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Comment: ok this solve my problem
    for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
{
    NSLog(@"%@", family);
        
    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
    {
        NSLog(@"  %@", name);
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Use this **fontNamesForFamilyName** property:

```
NSLog(@"family names : %@",[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"RemachineScript"]);
```

Hope it helps you.

and then check whteher you are using proper font name or not.

Comment: yes, I use the correct file, I try your suggest with "RemachineScript" and "Remachine Script" and I have no results

Comment: Is font name "RemachineScript" or "Remachine Script" available in font family names?